# Verilog: differences between if statement and case statement

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I am new to Verilog language and want to do some practices to get familiar with it. And I encountered this problem on HDLbits: [DFF8ar](https://hdlbits.01xz.net/wiki/Dff8ar)

This problem asks me to create 8 D flip-flops with active-high asynchronous reset. I use a `case` statement to handle the `areset` signal:

```
module top_module (
input clk,
input areset,   // active high asynchronous reset
input [7:0] d,
output reg[7:0] q
);

always @(posedge clk or posedge areset) begin
    case (areset)
        1'b1: q <= 8'b0; 
        default: q <= d;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

And to my surprise, the circuit it generated ignores the `clk` signal:
[image]

But, if I switch the `case` statement to an `if-else` statement, the result will be correct:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge areset) begin
    if (areset)
        q <= 8'b0; 
    else q <= d;
end
```

[image]

I don't know the reason behind it even after doing some research. Does `if-else` statements and `case` statements have some fundamental difference? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synthesis places some special restrictions on the normal Verilog language.
Synthesis tools recognize specific Verilog coding patterns, but your `case` code does not match any of those patterns, whereas your `if/else` code does. There should be documentation with your tool set that shows what syntax is supported for synthesis.  When you ran the synthesis, there may have been warning or error messages; check for any log files.

Although the 2 coding styles may behave the same in simulation, you need to restrict yourself to supported syntax for synthesis.